# too many input fields on a form

Tags: user-experience

I have a form which has about 15 fields a user has to input..I'm looking for a way to not scare the user's off.

I wanna see if someone implemented forms with too many fields differently or if anyone has any ideas

Comment: What kind of information you have? do you need ALL these fields?

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not all the fields are necessary because they depend on some choice, you could only display the relevant fields once the choice has been made. You could also visually distinguish non-mandatory fields so that it's clear from the outset how much work *has* to be done by the user and how much is optional.

If everything is mandatory, then you could either go the Windows way and show tons of small windows in sequence and annoy everyone who just wants to get it done, but you'd not scare people who get scared by seeing lots of forms - a page counter is crucial, though. However, you could *start* with a small wizard view, but immediately offer an "advanced" option that would allow those who want to show everything at once, while still offering a guided tour as the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep it in steps - maybe organize about 3 different pages filled with the forms.

Example: Contact info, they hit continue. Then they hit another page, except with the forms for ordering an item. Then the third page is for payment fields.